# How to teach a 3-year-old baby to not be afraid of bathing?

Tags: bathing, fears

Our 3-year-old girl is extremely afraid of bathing! We ask her why, but she just says "I just afraid". We tried putting toys in the water; she plays with them and the water but does not allow us to give her a shower. She just cries loudly and say to us "please give me up!"

She extremly hates water falling on her head and body, and we have to do this for her health :(

Anybody have any experience to help us, please? Thanks in advance!